# Cant install app from PlayStore for targetSDK 33

Tags: sdk, google-play-services, target, android-api-31

recently I released an Update for My App with targetsdk 33. Long Story short, its online right now, but you cant install it. You can basicly download the App but after that it says: somwthing whent wrong with the Instalation.

```
build.gradle

 applicationId "altenpflege.quiz"
        //minSdkVersion 32
        targetSdkVersion 33
        minSdk 19
        versionCode 16
        versionName '1.0.8e'
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

```
AndroidManifest
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="altenpflege.quiz">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> <!-- Required by older versions of Google Play services to create IID tokens -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="33"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Altenpflegequiz">

        <activity android:name="altenpflege.quiz.bootscreen"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="altenpflege.menues.MainMenue"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="altenpflege.menues.Hilfe"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".UserProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".resetpasswort"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.menues.MenueHaut"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.levels.Level1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:exported="true">


    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.levels.Level2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"            android:exported="true">


    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.levels.Level3"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="altenpflege.challange.Haut.QuizChallangeHaut" />
    <activity android:name="altenpflege.challange.Haut.QuizChallangeHautnormal" />
    <activity android:name="altenpflege.challange.Haut.QuizChallangeHautschwer" />
    <activity android:name="altenpflege.challange.Endo.QuizChallangeEndo" />
    <activity android:name="altenpflege.challange.Endo.QuizChallangeEndonormal" />
    <activity android:name="altenpflege.challange.Endo.QuizChallangeEndoschwer" />
    <activity android:name="altenpflege.challange.quizendoschwierigkeit" />
    <activity android:name="altenpflege.challange.blood.QuizChallangeBlutnormal" />
    <activity android:name="altenpflege.challange.quizbloodschwierigkeit" />
    <activity android:name="altenpflege.challange.ErgebnisHautChallange" />
    <activity android:name="altenpflege.challange.quizhautschwierigkeit" />
    <activity android:name=".ErgebniseLevels"/>

    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.challange.blood.QuizChallangeBlut"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.challange.blood.QuizChallangeBlutschwer"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.menues.MenueEndo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">


    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.menues.MenueBlut"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">


    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.levels.Level1E"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:exported="true">


    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.levels.Level2E"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.levels.Level3E"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.levels.Level1B"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.levels.Level2B"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.menues.MenueMDT"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.levels.Level3B"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.levels.LevelMDTA1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.levels.LevelMDTA2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.levels.LevelMDTA3"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name="altenpflege.levels.LevelMDTA4"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="628713182028"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I changed the API level, to fix the new Google Play policy since nov 22.

I changed the Java Version to 11.

Every Intent Value in the Manifest get: android:exported="true".

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it just had to delete `android:testOnly="true"` in the Manifest.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).